# Encode Decode html <a> tag in mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I have comment box when i type the comment and if comment have any link then i automatically convert to the link by following way.

```
protected string MakeLink(string txt)
        {
            Regex regx = new Regex("(http|https)://([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(txt);

            foreach (Match match in mactches)
            {
                txt = txt.Replace(match.Value, "<a href='" + match.Value + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
            }

            return txt;
        }
```

when i put the  tag will show like this 
" lt;a href='http://asd.com'gt;http://asd.com lt;/a gt; "  [ right now i removed & otherwise it create link in my Question. ]

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Html.Raw` method to print output of this method. This method renders unencoded HTML. More on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

The example you can find here: http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/

Answer (score 0):

+1 for previous answer.
Also you can use HtmlString type

```
protected HtmlString MakeLink(string txt)
        {
            Regex regx = new Regex("(http|https)://([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(txt);

            foreach (Match match in mactches)
            {
                txt = txt.Replace(match.Value, "<a href='" + match.Value + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
            }

            return new HtmlString(txt);
        }
```